# How to pass the result of a function as argument into a Bash function?

Tags: bash

I have this function:

```
test() {
  echo "$1"
}
```

`$1` can receive an argument.  This works:

```
test "i am here"
i am here
```

Now I want to receive the result of `date`.

```
date
Tue Jan 10 10:36:10 CST 2017

test   `date`
Tue
```

How to make **Jan 10 10:36:10 CST 2017** not be omitted?

Comment: It's not *omitted*, exactly, but passed as separate arguments, as expansions performed without quotes (with some exceptions, such as the right-hand side of assignments) go through string-splitting and globbing to form the list of words they evaluate to. `10` is `"$2"`, for instance. If you ran your code through http://shellcheck.net/, it would have caught the missing quoting leading to this.

Comment: BTW, the `$()` syntax is strongly preferred -- it's a mandatory part of POSIX sh, and thus portable, but also far easier to nest than backticks. (Writing `hello "$(cruel "$(world)")"` is trivial; its backtick-based equivalent... is not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose the result of `date` in double quotes for the entire date string to be sent as a single argument to your function:

```
test "`date`"
```

or, more preferably:

```
test "$(date)"
```

---

Here is an example:

```
$ test "$(date)"
Tue Jan 10 03:17:26 UTC 2017
```